# How can I pass input value from view to controller and model to fetch data correctly? Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to fetch a data that has the same id of my input hidden value.

I cannot fetch the id or input hidden value of the data

To start with, this is what I've done to make things clearer for me to debug things I made a hard coded form and a button to bring me to the page

In View - **groups/index.php**

> As you can see I made the `posts/index/1` which is a hard coded value but I can change that later easily that is not my problem

```
<?php echo form_open('posts/index/1') ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="txtGroup" value="1" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Submit</button>

</form>
```

So after I made the form I will make a function in controller to fetch the `posts/index`

In Controller - **Posts.php**

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('teachers/posts/index');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
}
```

And so I fetched the page. At this point, i can now go through `/posts/index/1` and see my page

In my page **posts/index.php** I have a data and it is fetched through Ajax here it is

> So I already fetched this data in `posts/showPosts`

```
showAllQuestions();

//Show all data
function showAllQuestions(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/showPosts',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
            var n=1;

            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                html +='<div class="card">'+
                    '<div class="card-header" style="color:white; background-color:black">'+
                        '<h4><span class="iconify" data-icon="ant-design:info-circle-outlined" data-inline="false"></span> Question No. '+ n++ +'</h4>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="card-body">'+
                        '<form>'+
                            '<div class="form-group">'+
                                '<label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1"><h5> <span class="iconify" data-icon="emojione:check-mark-button" data-inline="false"></span> </h5></label>'+
                                '<input type="text" value="'+data[i].question+'" class="form-control" disabled />'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<hr>'+
                            '<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>posts/edit/'+data[i].id+'" class="btn btn-info"><span class="iconify" data-icon="el:edit" data-inline="false"></span> </a>&nbsp;'+
                            '<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>posts/delete/'+data[i].id+'" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa-solid:trash-alt" data-inline="false"></span></a>'+
                            //  '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info item-edit" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">Edit </a>&nbsp;'+
                        '</form>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div><br>';
            }

            $('#showdata').html(html);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Could not get Data from Database');
        }
});
```

}

In `posts/showPosts` - Posts.php, this is the controller

```
public function showPosts(){
    $result = $this->post_model->showPosts();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Finally the Model to Determine if I fetched the correct ID depending on the data id I submit

> Problem is the $id is null and I don't have a clue to start with, because I declare a hidden input value on the view page.

```
public function showPosts(){
    // Show questions and answers
    $id = $this->input->post('txtGroup');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('questions');
    $this->db->where('group_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to understand this question better than your previous one (which is now safe to delete since this is a better description of your issue).

In your `groups/index.php` view, you want to allow a user to *navigate* to the `posts/index` page and pass an integer as a single parameter (which is hard-coded by you, not entered by the user) -- I'll refer to it as `$txtGroup` for context.  Because you are not performing a `INSERT`|`UPDATE`|`DELETE` operation, better practice is to send the data as a `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.  Because Codeigniter enables the passing of `$_GET` parameter as a slash-delimited extension of the url, I don't see any benefit in setting up a `<form>`.

Style your new hyperlink as a button using your preferred classes.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("posts/index/{$integer}"); ?>">Link to <?php echo $integer; ?></a>
```

This will send your data to the `posts/index.php` controller.  This is where you should be accessing/extracting the `$txtGroup` value from the url.

Here's where I start to get foggy about what you need.  If you want to pass the value to the `teachers/posts/index` view, then do so by passing an associative array as the second parameter when you load the view.

```
public function index($txtGroup) {
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    // if you want to pass the value to THIS 
    $this->load->view('teachers/posts/index', ['txtGroup' => $txtGroup]);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
}
```

---

If you are not interested in passing the `$txtGroup` to the view, then the only other reason to pass the value from `groups/index.php` to `posts/index` would be to modify a query and then pass dynamic data to the `teachers/posts/index` view (which you would need to supply when loading the view anyhow).

```
public function index($txtGroup) {
    $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->showPosts($txtGroup);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('teachers/posts/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
}
```

In your model, use the passed argument.

```
public function showPosts($groupId) {
    return $this->db->get_where('questions', ['group_id' => $groupId])->result_array();
}
```

This way, you don't need to use an ajax call (which looks like you are unconditionally triggering in your view anyhow).  Now Codeigniter will work its magic to transfer `$data` to your view whereby you can access the multidimensional result set as `$posts` (the variable is named by the first-level key that you assign it).  Use a `foreach()` loop to iterate the rows of results and generate your html content -- all using server-side language.

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $index => $post) { ?> 
    <div class="card">
    // ... the rest of your content ...
<?php } ?>
```

As you design the new dynamic content using the above loop:

- Use `$index` as your counter so that you don't have to manually increment.
- **DO NOT** allow `INSERT`|`UPDATE`|`DELETE` operations to be triggered by `$_GET` events, this is not best practice.  Those types of actions should only be initiated by `$_POST` submissions.

Comment: @Mana have you gone away?